# Use rollup to calculate grand totals with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, rollup

I have a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetReportData
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        LOC.SubCompanyNameVN,
        LOC.BranchName,
        COUNT(LOC.BranchCode) as Total,

        ----------- Not Processed Yet
        SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountNotProcessedYet,
        
        ----------- Processing
        SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountProcessing

    FROM 
        DBO.WorkingSession AS SS
    JOIN 
        DBO.Location AS LOC ON SS.LocationID = LOC.LocationID 
                            AND SS.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode
    JOIN 
        DBO.Status AS ST ON SS.Status = ST.ID
    GROUP BY 
        LOC.SubCompanyNameVN, LOC.BranchName
    ORDER BY 
        LOC.SubCompanyNameVN
END
```

The result:

| SubCompanyNameVN | BranchName | Total | CountNotProcessedYet | CountProcessing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vùng 1 | HNI_01 | 5 | 3 | 2 |
| Vùng 1 | HNI_02 | 15 | 5 | 10 |
| Vùng 1 | HNI_07 | 12 | 6 | 6 |
| Vùng 2 | HCM_01 | 86 | 50 | 36 |
| Vùng 2 | HCM_03 | 35 | 17 | 18 |

But now I expect my result to be:

| SubCompanyOrBranchName | Total | CountNotProcessedYet | CountProcessing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Vùng 1** | **32** | **14** | **18** |
| HNI_01 | 5 | 3 | 2 |
| HNI_02 | 15 | 5 | 10 |
| HNI_07 | 12 | 6 | 6 |
| **Vùng 2** | **121** | **67** | **54** |
| HCM_01 | 86 | 50 | 36 |
| HCM_03 | 35 | 17 | 18 |

How can I group the results by column SubCompanyNameVN (Group By SubCompanyNameVN) to calculate the total like the above table? I have researched and I think I can solve it with ROLLUP but I am confused about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as `ROLLUP`, you can also use `GROUPING SETS`, which gives you more flexibility in choosing the exact rollups you want.

> It's better to use the `GROUPING()` function rather than `ISNULL`, because this tells you if the column was actually grouped, and you can see the difference between that an actual `NULL`

```sql
 SELECT 
     CASE WHEN GROUPING(LOC.BranchName) = 0
       THEN LOC.BranchName
       ELSE LOC.SubCompanyNameVN
       END AS SubCompanyOrBranchName,
     COUNT(LOC.BranchCode) as Total,

     ----------- Not Processed Yet
     SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountNotProcessedYet,
     
     ----------- Processing
     SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountProcessing

 FROM 
     DBO.WorkingSession AS SS
 JOIN 
     DBO.Location AS LOC ON SS.LocationID = LOC.LocationID 
                         AND SS.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode
 JOIN 
     DBO.Status AS ST ON SS.Status = ST.ID
 GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
     (LOC.SubCompanyNameVN, LOC.BranchName),
     (LOC.SubCompanyNameVN)
 )
 ORDER BY 
     LOC.SubCompanyNameVN,
     GROUPING(LOC.BranchName) DESC, -- put the totalled rows first
     LOC.BranchName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `cte` and `union all` with `group by`

```
With cte AS ( 
     SELECT 
        LOC.SubCompanyNameVN,
        LOC.BranchName,
        COUNT(LOC.BranchCode) as Total,

        ----------- Not Processed Yet
        SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountNotProcessedYet,
        
        ----------- Processing
        SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountProcessing,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN ORDER BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN) AS seq

    FROM 
        DBO.WorkingSession AS SS
    JOIN 
        DBO.Location AS LOC ON SS.LocationID = LOC.LocationID 
                            AND SS.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode
    JOIN 
        DBO.Status AS ST ON SS.Status = ST.ID
    GROUP BY 
        LOC.SubCompanyNameVN, LOC.BranchName)
        
select SubCompanyNameVN,Total,CountNotProcessedYet,CountProcessing
from
(select SubCompanyNameVN,
       sum(Total) As Total,
       sum(CountNotProcessedYet) As CountNotProcessedYet,
       sum(CountProcessing) As CountProcessing,
       dense_rank()over(order by SubCompanyNameVN) As rnk
   from cte
   group by SubCompanyNameVN
   union all
   select BranchName,
       Total,
       CountNotProcessedYet,
       CountProcessing,
       dense_rank()over(order by SubCompanyNameVN) As rnk
   from cte) T
order by rnk,SubCompanyNameVN desc
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=220627e29c65e5b75c59034eb09ea029)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution finally by using `ROLLUP`, here is what I need:

```
SELECT 
        (CASE 
            WHEN
                BranchName is NULL
                    THEN SubCompanyNameVN ELSE BranchName
        END) AS SubCompanyOrBranchName,
        Total, CountNotProcessedYet, PercentNotProcessedYet, CountProcessing, PercentProcessing,
        CountProcessedIn5Days, PercentProcessedIn5Days, CountProcessedOver5Days, PercentProcessedOver5Days
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            LOC.SubCompanyNameVN,
            LOC.BranchName,
            COUNT(LOC.BranchCode) as Total,
            ----------- Not Processed Yet
            SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountNotProcessedYet,
        
            ----------- Processing
            SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountProcessing

        FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS SS
        JOIN DBO.Location AS LOC ON SS.LocationID = LOC.LocationID AND SS.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode
        JOIN DBO.Status AS ST ON SS.Status = ST.ID
        GROUP BY ROLLUP(LOC.SubCompanyNameVN, LOC.BranchName)
        ORDER BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN, LOC.BranchName OFFSET 1 ROWS
    ) T
```